# Eclipse is not uploading new project changes

Tags: android, build

I have an android project I was working on months ago and today I decided to pick it up and keep going.  The first thing I realized was that I had a photo that was too small for the screen so I went ahead and completely removed it and re-ran the program; however when it was uploaded to my device the photo was still there.  I figured I did something wrong so I kept playing with it.  Then after a while I thought maybe there is a different issue so I made a more drastic change and changed the intent to send my application to a different page; however when I re-ran it, the application still brought me to the old page.  I do not understand why this is happening and the other people online seemed to be having a different problem in which eclipse didn't noticed their changes and wasn't rebuilding so they were able to fix this by adding and deleting a line; however my issue is more drastic.

Here is what console says:

```
[2013-02-26 19:39:18 - Para Raiders] Android Launch!

[2013-02-26 19:39:18 - Para Raiders] adb is running normally.

[2013-02-26 19:39:18 - Para Raiders] Performing com.synlight_development.para_raiders.Main activity launch

[2013-02-26 19:39:18 - Para Raiders] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'eb1f246c'

[2013-02-26 19:39:18 - Para Raiders] Uploading Para Raiders.apk onto device 'eb1f246c'

[2013-02-26 19:39:19 - Para Raiders] Installing Para Raiders.apk...

[2013-02-26 19:39:22 - Para Raiders] Success!

[2013-02-26 19:39:22 - Para Raiders] Starting activity 
com.synlight_development.para_raiders.Main on device eb1f246c

[2013-02-26 19:39:23 - Para Raiders] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.synlight_development.para_raiders/.Main }
```

Comment: What does your console output say? (not your logcat)

Comment: I updated it above...

Comment: You did clean project and all that good stuff, right?

Comment: I have cleaned the project, updated all the SDK and ADT Plugins and I am still having the same error...

Comment: Make an obvious change (i.e. change app name in manifest) and redeploy. See if that makes it to the app drawer. If it does, then your updated package is on the device, but the changes you made don't apply. If you only made layout changes, keep in mind that you need to apply them to all layout folders. Had a bear of a time once getting layout changes to a device, because I didn't realize it was classified "large"

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it seems like your application is not deployed to your device.
This can happen due to the following reasons (non taxative)

- Your project does not compile, hence no new APK is released to the device.
- Your project contains errors which makes it unable to be packed into an APK.
- Your project now uses a different signing key - Android may not override the existing application with the new one.

I would suggest, see the Console Output from Eclipse (the reason will be printed there) as well as uninstall your application from the device (Settings => Apps => "Your application" => "Uninstall" or from the CLI `adb uninstall com.my.package`). You will then get a clean environment (user data is deleted as well) which makes development easier.

Also, make sure you deploy/run the RIGHT project (in case you have multiple projects in your workspace) - to ensure this, right click on your MainActivity in the project explorer, select "Run As" and choose "Android Application".

Comment: I have tried uninstalling the old apk too.  That didn't work, I tried that twice earlier today...

Comment: You uninstalled the app (so it is deleted from the device), you deploy it again and - applied changes are not visible - correct? Are you sure you deploy the right application?

Comment: @Josh Remove the app and check in the application manager that it was in fact removed.

Comment: I am updating all the android SDKs and maybe that will fix it.  I did remove the application fully...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app and check in the application manager that it was in fact removed. Then clean and rebuild your project before reinstalling.

Comment: @Josh What happened at each step? Please edit your OP with as much detail as will be helpful in answering your question, but no more. Screenshots from your device will be helpful.

Comment: I run it as I usually do however this applicaiton is not showing my changes when I update it...

Comment: @Josh And I guess you expect me to just know how you usually run your program. If you really want help, you need to provide a lot more detail.